# Which grade of PVC piping do I need in order to sustain a 1,000Pa vacuum?

Tags: pvc, vacuum

I'm rigging a proof of concept DIY machine, in which the internal pressure will need to be at most 1/50th of atmospheric pressure. For a safety margin, I want the machine to withstand 1/100th atmospheric pressure (or about 1,000 pascals). What grade of PVC piping do I need in order to prevent implosion? Or, is PVC piping, not the best suited for the job? I don't have access to a laboratory, so things I can pick up at a store would be ideal. Many thanks.

Comment: Just FYI, there's absolutely no practical difference between having 1/50th or 1/100th of atmospheric pressure inside when it comes to designing the walls to cope with it. Both of those are negligible compared to the atmospheric pressure outside (100 kPa). A difference of 1 kPa is even below normal fluctuation of atmospheric pressure.

Comment: PVC would be a bad choice. Likely has the same problems in an implosion as it does in an explosion, which is why it's forbidden for compressed air service. Plenty strong until it sharts cracking, and the cracks propagate *really fast,* and shrapnel flies everywhere. Ordinary copper or iron pipe is more than strong enough, or thick-walled flexible plastic or rubber hose/tubing (walls have to be thick enough it does not flatten) - polyethlene well pipe (rigid on a small scale, flexible on a large scale) works fine, and does not have PVC's problems. A compressed air hose would also be fine.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thank you for explaining that. That makes sense, and I'm going to try the copper route. I don't have the tools needed to drill iron, and the tools needed are a bit pricy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe grade PVC pipe can service the pressure satisfactorily. See information below.

[image]

https://www.aciplas.com.br/assets/technical_manual_pvc_cpvc_sch_80_e_40.pdf